# Poor pickup of my car

Tags: car, maruti, wagonr

I am facing poor pick up on my car.It has become quite rough.
I have recently changed engine oil,transmission oil,air filter.Its a 2009 make maruti suzuki wagonr duo(its a dual fuel car LPG/Petrol) 
Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Comment: Which fuel mode are you getting the pickup problems on? Are you getting any engine codes?

Comment: Have you changed /cleaned the plugs?

Comment: On LPG I get poor pick up.Yes I have cleaned the plugs